# Text shifted up in the textView while i focus on Textview second time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I use Textview for insert message text but when i focus in textview second time after insert some text then already inserted text shifted upside. so text cut in the TextView.
Any solution for this problem?

Comment: How is your blog related to this issue? Are you trying to abuse stackoverflow to improve your google page ranking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextView  the subclass of UIScrollView. So you can discard scroll to top like this:

```
((UIScrollView*)someTextView).delegate = self; // or some other UIScrollViewDelegate
```

and implement this method:

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*) scrollView {
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
}
```

But if you do need scrolling during edit, you can add some boolean flags to distinguish the situations when user is scrolling and when the scrolling is automatic.